# VS2012 Scroll Bar "Full Mode" Bright in Dark Theme

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I love the full map of my code as a Scroll Bar in VS2012, but it seems as if it does not adopt the theme. I get a bright codemap in an otherwise dark-themed Visual Studio, and that is kind of disturbing. I am pretty sure the map should adopt the scheme, so what could have gone wrong here?

[Edit:]
Seems there already exists a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779654/productivity-power-tools-forgets-source-map-color-preferences-when-changing-color-schemes).

Comment: can you post a screenshot? (I'm friends with some of the VS devs, I can let them know).

Comment: I just discovered, it is actually part of the Productivity Power Tools. I guess I could, but you really would not get any more information out of it. The "enhanced scroll bar" that shows the whole file's contents as an overview hast the code highlighting of the bright/blue theme. (and, more annoying, the white background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the Productivity Power Tools with Dark Theme active (including the restarts) and then going back and forth between Dark and Bright Theme solved the issue.

However, there is a already a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779654/productivity-power-tools-forgets-source-map-color-preferences-when-changing-color-schemes) filed on MS Connect, so chances are this will be fixed in a future update of the Productivity Power Tools.